# How to avoid creating new targets in Xcode when there is only one file difference?

Tags: xcode, code-organization, project-organization

We have an Xcode project with about 300-400 files in it. And we have different clients with different graphics. For each client we have have a new target and we build our app for production, test and development. For this we have a production target, test target and a development target, and they use the same files (except the icon file and a couple of others) and have the similar settings.

So our targets look like this:

```
Client1Development
Client1Test
Client1Production
Client2Development
Client2Test
Client2Production
Client2PenetrationTesting

...
and so on
```

This becomes more problematic as we have more clients (around 15). It makes the xproj bigger to work with (now it's about 8 MB), and it sometimes causes bugs when we add a new file and forget to include it in one of the targets.

Could it be possible to manage this somehow and only have the targets like this:

```
Client1
Client2
...
```

I was thinking to use different schemas, but from a schema I can not enforce which icon file to include at build time. Should I look for a way of writing a script, or maybe it's better to have the targets as they are now?

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with building from the command line, it would be fairly easy to take the client selection as a script parameter, rearrange the assets as necessary, and invoke xcodebuild on one of your three targets.